# Homebrew link issue on Mac OS X (10.7.5)

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm having issues troubleshooting a link problem when installing Homebrew.  I'm attempting to install it on Mac OS X (10.7.5).  I have been unable to find a solution and could use help.  The error I'm receiving is below.

```
tone$ brew link wget
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.14... Warning: Could not link wget. Unlinking...

Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.14/share/man/man1/wget.1
Target /usr/local/share/man/man1/wget.1 already exists. You may need to delete it.
To force the link and overwrite all other conflicting files, do:
  brew link --overwrite formula_name

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run formula_name
```

I ran the following commands to get to this point

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"

$ brew install wget
```

Comment: have you tried doing what it asks you to do? as in delete the file or run the command with the --overwrite option?

Comment: oh my gawd.  I manually deleted it and of course it worked.  I was actually afraid to delete it and was unsure how to write the overwrite command.  Thanks for pointing out the obvious Brad.  I got it working.  Appreciated.